# Change language of eclipse plugin in code

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am developing eclipse rcp application, it is supporting English and German language, and we are using -Duser.language=de parameter to change the application language.

Now the problem is I have used eclipse help plugin to display help and created toc contents for the same. Help is displaying properly but there is one issue, In Help dialog, it is still showing title in english i.e. Help .

Please let me know how to change the eclipse API language when application is running on different language apart from english.

Comment: If you are using help dialog, which is provided by eclipse you need to have also proper localizations bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse uses the `-nl locale` command line argument - this is equivalent to setting the `osgi.nl` environment variable.

More on the command line arguments [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html)

Comment: I am already using the parameter -nl de while launching the application, but with no success. Do we need to set any setting in eclipse preference/somewhere else to make eclipse internal plugins work for language apart from english?